# Wait until enclosure's async method completes javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am new to javascript programming. I just can't find an answer that works.

The problem is that my function only works when it is wrapped in setTimeout call like so:

```
var sPageIdentifier = 'ReportViewer';
UserPreferencesManager.Initialize(sPageIdentifier);
setTimeout(function () {
var strUserPrefs = UserPreferencesManager.GetPreferences();
    console.log(strUserPrefs);
   initLayout(strUserPrefs);
}, 1000);

function initLayout(strUserPrefs) {
    //do stuff using strUserPrefs
}
```

If I comment out setTimeout function, the initLayout(strUserPrefs) fails because strUserPrefs is null.
Any help will be appreciated!

Here is the UserPreferencesManager.js code:

```
var UserPreferencesManager = function () {
  var strPrefsID = null;
  var strPrefsString = null;

  return {

    Initialize: function (strPrefsIDIn) {
      strPrefsID = strPrefsIDIn;
      strPrefsString = this.GetPreferences();
    },

    GetPreferences: function () {
      if (!strPrefsID) {
        alert("Validation Failed: the UserPreferencesManager must be initialized prior to usage.");
        return null;
      }
      if (!strPrefsString) {
        this.LoadPreferences();
        return strPrefsString;
      }
      return strPrefsString;
    },
    LoadPreferences: function () {
      if (!strPrefsID) {
        alert("Validation Failed: the UserPreferencesManager must be initialized prior to usage.");
        return null;
      }    
      myasyncfunctioncall({
        parameters: ["USR_PersonId", "abc", 'GET']
        script_name: 'MAINTAIN_USER_PREFS',
        onexception: function (exception, xhr, options) {
          alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText + +exception);
          console.log(exception);
        },
        onsuccess: function (data, xhr, options) {
          if (data == "User ID is zero") {
            alert('MP_MAINTAIN_USER_PREFS: must be > 0.0');
            strPrefsString = data;
          }
          else {
            strPrefsString = data;
          }
        }
      });
    },// end of LoadPreferences

    WritePreferences: function (strPrefsIn, strPrefsID) {
      if (strPrefsID && typeof strPrefsID === "string") {
        if (strPrefsIn != null) {

          myasyncfunctioncall({
            parameters: ["USR_PersonId", strPrefsID, strPrefsIn , 'SET']
            script_name: 'MAINTAIN_USER_PREFS',
            onexception: function (exception, xhr, options) {
              alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText + +exception);
              console.log(exception);
            },
            onsuccess: function (data, xhr, options) {
              if (data == "transaction-ok") {
                UserPreferencesManager.LoadPreferences();
              } else if (data == "User ID is zero") {
                alert('MP_MAINTAIN_USER_PREFS: must be > 0.0');
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          alert("Error: Preferences object must be initialized prior to writing preferences");
        }
      } else {
        alert('Error: The preference ID can\'t be null and must to be of type string');
        return;
      }
    }// end of WritePreferences
  };// end of return API

}(); // end of UserPreferencesManager
```

Comment: Learn about deferred objects/promises: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip, Balachandra!
Here is what I did, added two parameters to LoadPreferences method - callback and strPrefsID, so I can invoke fnCallback function within on success and pass it ajax data:

```
LoadPreferences: function (fnCallback, strPrefsID) {
    if (!strPrefsID) {
        alert("Validation Failed: the BhsUserPreferencesManager must be initialized prior to usage.");
        return null;
    }
    if (strPrefsString) {
        // strPrefsString is not null, so return it
        callback(strPrefsString);
    } else {
        myasyncfunctioncall({
            parameters: ["USR_PersonId", "abc", 'GET']
            script_name: 'MAINTAIN_USER_PREFS',
            onexception: function (exception, xhr, options) {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText + +exception);
                console.log(exception);
            },
            onsuccess: function (data, xhr, options) {
                if (data == "User ID is zero") {
                    alert('MAINTAIN_USER_PREFS: must be > 0.0');
                    strPrefsString = data;
                } else if (data.substring(0, 5) === "ERROR") {
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    fnCallback(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}// end of LoadPreferences
```

And here is how now I can call initLayout:

```
BhsUserPreferencesManager.LoadPreferences(initLayout, sPageIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seens like this  myasyncfunctioncall is sending an async request. You'll need to add some variable to set if the response of this async request has arrived, and then, when it is set you can continue with your routine.

WHenever an async call is made on javascript, the program continues as if it was already completed. You have to mannually add checks to see if it has completed or not.

Answer (score 0):

UserPreferencesManager.GetPreferences() is Making the asynchronous AJAX call to get the user preferences. So, in this case Javascript thread will continue execution in current thread context and executes initLayout(strUserPrefs). But at this state GetPreferences() call is still not complete and strUserPrefs is null.

SetTimeout is one of the trick to overcome this issue, which you did. But you can also design the APIs in such a way that it allows the callback function execution for each asynchronous AJAX calls.